# Perform calculation in Pandas if string condition met from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
Day    Sales    Qty     Paid
1        10      2        Y
2        20      5        N
3        30      5        N
4        20      6        Y
5        50      2        Y
```

I am simply hoping to create another column that multiplies `Sales` and `Qty` if the `Paid` column = `Y`and if not `Y` then calculate `0 - df['Qty']`

I tried:

```
df['total'] = df['Paid'].apply(lambda x: df['Sales']*df['Qty'] if x == 'Y' else (0-df['Qty'])
```

I'm getting an `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`

Also open to quicker/more efficient ways to do this process. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is `print(df.dtypes)` ? looks like you have some numbers as string

Comment: ah yes there are some values with text so i will need to convert them to 0s. Ill give that a go

Comment: Bdw you can try vectorized methods: `np.where(df['Paid']=='Y',df['Sales']*df['Qty'],0-df['Qty'])` instead of apply

Comment: do I use that following `df['total'] = `?

Comment: yes `df['total']=np.where(df['Paid']=='Y',df['Sales']*df['Qty'],0-df['Qty'])`

Comment: Great - it worked well after i removed the strings. Thanks for your help - problem answered!